# Quit all hidden/invisible windows

Tags: windows, vba

Sometimes I use the command `ie.visible = False` which hides the window even though it still exists.

How can I close all the hidden windows ?

My actual solution is to log out from my computer's session and log in again...there is probably a better way to do this.

I tried `Set ie = Nothing` or `ie.Quit` but it doesn't affect the hidden windows since when I count them with

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
```

they are still there.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a couple of hidden internet explorer windows and did a before and after count of the open internet explorer windows and the below code seems to work:

```
Public Sub CLOSE_HIDDEN_IE()

    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim SH As SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    Set SH = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    For Each IE In SH
    If IE.Visible = False Then
        IE.Quit
     End If
    Next

    Set IE = Nothing
    Set SH = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code loops through the open internet explorer window and closes the ones which aren't visible.

Happy to help if you need anything.

Comment: Yes it works, it seems so obvious actually ! The weird thing is that it doesn't close all of them at once. I mean that I have to run this code a few times before reaching the right number, but that's just a small detail. Thanks man !

Comment: You could try something along the lines of this:

    `While Now() < Time + 0.00005
        While SH.Count <> 0
            For Each IE In SH
                If IE.Visible = False Then
                    IE.Quit
                End If
            Next
        Wend
    Wend`

This will run the script for five seconds or until `sh.count = 0.`

Comment: Though, bear in mind VBA doesn't support multi-threading and therefore the five seconds will need to pass before you do anything else. Just mentioned it as food for thought. Happy to help.